# Shell: Get a list of latest files by filename

Tags: shell

I have files like

```
update-1.0.1.patch
update-1.0.2.patch
update-1.0.3.patch
update-1.0.4.patch
update-1.0.5.patch
```

And I have a variable that contains the last applied path (e.g. update-1.0.3.patch). So, now I have to get a list of files to apply (in the example updates 1.0.4 and 1.0.5). How can I get such list?

To clarify, I need a method to get a list of files that *comes alphabetically later* of given file and this list of files must be also in alphabetical order (obviously is not allways possible to apply the patch 1.0.5 before 1.0.4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` is your go-to guy for printing ranges of lines. You give it a starting/ending address or pattern and command to do between.

```
ls update-1.0.* | sort | sed -ne "/$ENVVAR/,// p"
```

The sort probably isn't necessary because `ls` can sort by name, but it might be good to include as a courtesy to maintainers to show the necessity. The `-n` to sed means "don't print every line automatically" and the `-e` means "I'm giving you a script on the command line". I used " to enclose the script to that `$ENVVAR` would be eval'd. The ending address is empty (`//`) and the `p` means "print the line".

Oh, and I just noticed you only want the ones later. There's probably a way to tell sed to start on the line after your address, but instead I'd pipe it through `tail -n +2` to start on the second line.

Comment: Great, only one problem. This returns also the $ENVVAR content, in my example update-1.0.3 that was already applied. How can get rid of this first update? Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer to fix that. Add a pipe on the end through `tail`. Or read the manual on `sed` to figure out how to add 1 to the address....